# Detecting web service failures in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http-status-codes

I have an ASP.NET web application that calls a web service on a remote server. I want the application to be able to detect when it is not able to access the web service because of any sort of failure on the remote server.

It is essential that the application can differentiate between a failure on the remote server and a failure due to other circumstances. For example, it must be able to detect the difference between the web service url having been blocked by a firewall and the Http service on the remote server being unavailable.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this, please? Ideally the solution will use the HttpStatusCode returned on the HttpWebResponse object.

Comment: are you using WCF, an old-fashioned web reference, or just manually constructing an HttpWebResponse?

Comment: WCF, but to test the connection, using an HttpWebResponse may be the most lightweight approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a try clause around the code that calls the remote server and then catch a WebException.  Inside the WebException object will be a HttpWebResponse with the status code and other tasty information about the response from the remote server.

```
try
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://remote.service.com/getdata");
    request.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse
}
catch (WebException wx)
{
    HttpWebResponse webExceptionResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wx.Response;
    var sr = new StreamReader(webExceptionResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    string jsonResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
    HttpStatusCode status = webExceptionResponse.StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sanpaco, I see there is a status code on the WebException object too with other useful information. 

I should be able to safely use the Http 500 status to determine if there are any application problems in the web service itself. 

Any idea how I which status would show that the web server on which the service is hosted is down?

Comment: Usually a `503 Service Unavailable` indicates that the remote server is down or off.  Although, I'm not sure if you would get the same if the service is just behind a firewall.  In my experience calling other services like this, I usually just have to call admins of the service to verify why I'm getting the specific error.  But I think you are pretty safe assuming that any 500 range status means there is a problem with the remote server.